# Storing Reverse String in 2D Array

Tags: java

I am trying to get the contents of a string, and store it in the last row of my 2D array here is what I have so far:

```
char[][] square = new char[5][5];
String number = new String("three");
for(int k = number.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--)
{
      square[4][k] = number.charAt(k);
}
```

The output the code is giving me is the string in non reversed order.

Isn't this the logic for reversing a string? All I am doing here is setting the fourth column, and all rows starting at the end of the string to it's value. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: It prints the string in its current state, not reversed

Comment: Where are you printing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just walk through the loop by hand.

The first time through, k is 4.

So, square[4][4] is set to the character returned by .charAt(4), which is an 'e'.

then square[4][3] becomes 'e', ... and square[4][0] becomes 't'.

square[4] now reads t,h,r,e,e.

You've basically reversed both ends. Try this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < number.length(); k++) {
    square[4][k] = number.charAt(number.length() - k - 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So simple, went straight over my head. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you're not reversing it. You're setting the same character back again at the same position. If you need it reversed then the logic should be

`square[4][number.length() - (k + 1)] = number.charAt(k);`

Answer (score 0):

You need a different index beyond `square[4][k]` when you are also copying the value from `number.charAt(k)` - that is, you are copying the characters backwards (but into the array also backward). There is no need to call `new String(String)`. You could do

```
char[][] square = new char[5][5];
String number = "three";
for (int i = 0; i < number.length(); i++) {
    int k = number.length() - i - 1;
    square[4][k] = number.charAt(i);
}
```

But I would prefer a `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder.reverse()` myself. Like,

```
char[][] square = new char[5][5];
String number = "three";
square[4] = new StringBuilder(number).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
```